# GCC STL bound checking

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, bounds-checker

How do I enable bound checking for `operator[]` and iterators?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can activate runtime iterator and bounds checking by compiling with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. Also note that random-access containers provide the always bounds-checking `at()`-operation in addition to `operator []`.

References:

GCC STL debug mode: 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode

at() operation: [`std::vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), [`std::deque::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) and [`std::array::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at)

Comment: Note that using Debug Mode changes ABI, so you can't mix modules compiled with and without `-DGLIBCXX_DEBUG`.

Comment: @Ruslan The correct symbol name is `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`.

Answer (score 1):

you should overload the `operator[]` for your specific classes.  If you want to use an existing STL container, the `at()` function is a bounds-checked version of the `operator[].`