# Assertion fails/Exceptions for STL

Tags: c++, stl, standard-library

Suppose I've an empty list L. Currently if I run L.front(), it will merrily execute returning a garbage value. Is there some option I can turn on such that executing this would throw an exception or result in an assertion failure?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on STL implementation you are using. Please provide some more details.

Comment: g++ 4..6. I've accepted kert's answer as it provides details for both MSVC and g++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GCC STL checked iterators](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode)

[MSVC checked iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx) ( on by default )

[STLPort debug mode, with checked iterators](http://www.stlport.org/doc/debug_mode.html)

[Previous question on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking)

Comment: Regarding MSVC, they're on by default for debug builds. For release builds, they're off by default in VC++ 2010 and on by default in VC++ 2008 and 2005.

Answer (score 2):

Use `empty()` to check if the list is empty. `size()` is not good here because it could have linear runtime. See more details in [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629). `empty()` has constant runtime and it is a standard way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual C++ 2010 (and probably earlier versions) then you can enable secure SCL and iterator debugging by using these two macros:

```
#define _SECURE_SCL 1
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 1
```

The other standard libraries may have that too.

Edit: Just as has been suggested, there is a single macro in VC2010, that is `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` which has 3 levels defined like this:

```
#if _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING
    #define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 2
#elif _SECURE_SCL
    #define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 1
#else
    #define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0
#endif
```

Comment: Actually, those are the macros for VC++ 2005 and 2008. For VC++ 2010, they have been replaced by a single macro, `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`. (Yes, I realize MSDN doesn't mention this.)

Comment: Please, don't define these macros yourself. Getting them right is *hard*, [Stephen Lavavej also discourages this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-3-of-n). Also, VS2010 has `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`. In debug mode it is set to `2`, which is full debugging. you can redefine *that* macro, but please let the other as they are.

Comment: @Xeo: I don't like messing with macros, but sometimes you have to. For example, standard doesn't prohibit from evaluating invalid iterators as long as they are not used, so `&*container.end();` is a perfectly good expression, but it would cause VC code to crash with SCL exception unless you disable it.

Comment: @Gene : Why would you think `&*container.end();` is valid? Dereferencing any end iterator is illegal.

Comment: @Gene: What @ildjarn says and *why the heck would you want to do that?!*

Comment: @ildjarn: I don't currently have time to browse the standard, but I'm sure it does allow dereferencing as long as it is not used.
@Xeo: it's quite common if you have an algorithm that, for example, takes pointers and you have only iterators, e.g. `algo(&*str.begin(), &*str.end());`

Comment: @Gene : No, you can't, and it's §24.1/5. If your code does this, it's wrong; if it appears to work correctly, you've just been lucky. The legal way to write that (assuming the memory underlying the iterators is contiguous, which **no** non-pointer iterator category can guarantee) is `algo(&*str.begin(), &*str.begin() + str.size());`

Answer (score 0):

Some standard libraries do offer such an option. You'd need to consult the documentation and/or code foryour particular implementation/compiler in order to determine its characteristics and how to enable it.

Alternately you could use a memory checker like valgrind or Purify instead of doing it in the library level.