# setting up system for program debugging buffer overflow

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, buffer, buffer-overflow

I remember reading a long time ago that if I want to test for buffer overflows on my linux box that I need to set something in the system to allow it to happen.  I can't remember exactly what it was for, but I was hoping some one knew what I was talking about.

I want to be able to test my programs for vulnerabilities, and see if the registers are overwritten.

EDIT:  I am running ubuntu 10.04

Comment: You seem to be asking for two things: "buffer overflows" and "register overwrites". Can you be a little more careful in your terminology?

Comment: Do you insist on an ubuntu based solution?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a memory debugger such as [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).  Note, however, that Valgrind only tracks for buffer overflows on dynamically-allocated memory.

If you have the option to use C++ instead of C, then you can switch to using containers rather than raw arrays, and harness GCC's "checked container" mode (see [GCC STL bound checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking)).  I'm sure other compilers offer similar tools.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint (in addition of [Oli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8555906/841108)), when chasing memory bugs with the `gdb` debugger, is to disable [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), with e.g.

```
 echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

After doing that, two consecutive runs of the same deterministic program will usually [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) regions at the same addresses (from one run to another), and this helps a lot debugging with `gdb` (because then `malloc` usually gives the same result from one run to another, at the same given location in the run).

You can also use the `watch` command of `gdb`.  In particular, if in a first run (with ASLR disabled) you figure that the location 0x123456 is changing unexepectedly, you could give `gdb` the following command in its second run:

```
 watch * (void**) 0x123456
```

Then `gdb` will break when this location changes (sadly, it has to be `mmap`-ed already).