# std::vector debug and release build using g++

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GCC STL bound checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking)

Is there something like a automatic debug version of the std:vector in the g++ STL and if not how could I achive one?

What I want is to specify a debug parameter in my g++ call for example:

```
g++ -D DEBUG_ main.cpp
```

When this parameter is defined I want all my std::vectors to check their boundarys when accesing an element, the way when using vector::at().

When the parameter is omitted I want all vectors to behave as if the normal [] operator is used, meaning no performance is "wasted" for boundary checking.

I heard that VC++ does something like this. So my question is how to to this using the g++?

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about the performance waste from using `at` over `operator[]`.

Comment: @chris: You might not be, but some of us are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flag you want is `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`

More debug options for libstdc++ can be found at:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode

Answer (score 0):

in debug mode you can have additional assertion and checking, but using `at()` or `[]` it's always on your side.

`at()` - throws out_of_bounds exception, `[]` - don't