# std::vector<T>::resize(n) vs reserve(n) with operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, language-lawyer

Numerous questions/answers inform me that `std::vector<T>::resize(n)` will increase capacity and size, whilst `std::vector<T>::reserve(n)` only increases capacity.

One example is [Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve).

A comment in that question indicates that after use of `reserve(n)`, the use of

`vec[i less than n] = ..`

is undefined behaviour, and many examples given are claimed to lead to segfaults.

When I compile and run

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void f(const std::vector<double> &s) {
    std::cout << "s.size() = " << s.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s.capacity() = " << s.capacity() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::size_t n = 20121;
    
    std::vector<double> a;
    a.reserve(2*n);
    a[n] = 2.5;
    std::cout << "a["<<n<<"] = " << a[n] << std::endl;
    f(a);
    
    std::vector<double> b;
    b.resize(2*n);
    b[n] = 2.5;
    std::cout << "b["<<n<<"] = " << b[n] << std::endl;
    f(b);
}
```

my output is

> a[20121] = 2.5
>
> s.size() = 0
>
> s.capacity() = 40242
>
> b[20121] = 2.5
>
> s.size() = 40242
>
> s.capacity() = 40242

#### Questions:

Has there been a change that makes this ok? Is this just my compiler (`g++ v5.2.0`) giving me undefined, but nice, behaviour?

As a second point of curiosity, why does `f(a)` tell me the size is 0 (guessed answer: no `push_back` calls), even though `a[n]` returns a valid value?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. "Appears to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. `f(a)` tells you that the size is 0 because the size is in fact 0; as you yourself mentioned at the start, `reserve()` modifies capacity but not size.

Comment: Try [`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking)

Comment: It is UB. Use class type (`std::string` or so) instead of vector `double`. Maybe a more complex type would cause your program result in crash.

Comment: Define "nice" undefined behavior! I would want the compiler to crash the program if I trigger undefined behavior. I consider it hostile to rather do something some people might expect! Run your code with some of the sanitizers and there should be a report of the issue: that's "nice".

Comment: @dyp `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` refuses to compile with `out-of-bounds`, which is perhaps more 'nice' in this case.

Comment: @Nawaz Using `std::string` gives me the same result as with `double`, but I see the point you're making.

Comment: You really need to read [What is undefined behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition "Undefined Behavior" means that the result that you see on the execution of that line is not defined and can/will change with different runs.

> Is this just my compiler (g++ v5.2.0) giving me undefined, but nice,
>   behaviour?

The nice behavior can be a mix of how std::vector is implemented in the version you are compiling and the state of memory when your program was executed. The compiler has almost no role to play in showing a "nice behavior".

One line answer: What you are noticing is indeed undefined behavior. The runtime is free to give any output/behavior including shooting monkeys out of your monitor, on hitting an UB.

Answer (score 0):

As always with undefined behavior, your compiler *may* produce what you might think would be a "reasonable/nice" behavior, *but the fact that you're seeing "nice" behavior doesn't mean that what you're doing is okay!* This behavior may change at any time, with any new version of the compiler, when you compile and/or run it on any other machine or OS, or when you re-run your program during a different lunar phase.