# C++:when accessing an empty string's element,there is no error,why?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
int main(){
    string s;
    std::cout << "size:" << s.size() << " "
                      << "capacity:" << s.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s[3] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I defined a empty **string** object, named **s**.
Both the **s.size()** and **s.capacity()** are **zero**, but when accessing the element **s[3]**,there is no segment fault, why ?

Comment: Undefined behavior is all you can expect in this case. This may or may not crash your program. That uncertainty is exactly why it is strongly advised *not* to do it!

Comment: Definitely undefined behavior. what might make this not crash is maybe the small string optimization of the standard library implementation that you're using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting aside the fact that (as explained by the others) this is UB and that (speaking academically) anything could happen, the specific reason in this specific case that you did not get a Segmentation Fault is that the operating system does not detect all memory accesses outside of your allocated objects -- it only detects when your invalid memory access is *so* wrong that it is to 0x0 or another page of virtual memory entirely, one with which your process was not furnished. That is the only level of "automatic" memory error detection that exists.

For more than that, your computer would have to inspect every memory access and compare it against the map of blocks allocated in the free store (which is very slow; you can do this during debugging using tools like *electric fence* and *valgrind*, though) or you would have to add index checking yourself (e.g. using `.at()` instead of `[]`).

C++ is a safe language to some degree, but there are still plenty of features that feel "bare-bones", inherited from C, where you maintain responsibility for knowing what you're doing, and cannot rely on your computer to tell you when you've done it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

segfault is not bound to happen when you access a memory you don't own, it *can* happen.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking something called undefined behaviour. It could crash, it could do nothing, it could do what you intended. Nothing is guaranteed. The behaviour is quite literally "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

Because many errors in C++ have no defined effects but instead result in **undefined behaviour**. Passing an impossible index to `std::string`'s `operator[]` is an example of such an error. Anything or nothing can happen.

This is because *requiring* compilers to create programs which perform all kinds of error checking at runtime would severely reduce the usability of C++ in usage scenarios where the overhead of error checking would be unacceptable. Generally, if you want runtime error checking like this in C++, then you have to **ask** for it (and pay for it).

A rather simplistic way would be to use the `at` member function, which is required to throw exceptions for illegal string indices. But how would you "handle" an exception like this, other than with an ugly `catch` in `main` which logs an error and quits?

An illegal string index should be treated as a **bug** which has to be fixed, not "handled" at runtime. Fortunately, there are ways to tell compilers to add detection of a wrong `operator[]` at runtime. Here's some more information:

- [GCC STL bound checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx

---

Note that only `size` is relevant to determine whether accessing an element is undefined behaviour or not. `capacity` is not.