# GCC8.2 How to enable warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]

Tags: c++, c, arrays, gcc8

I want to enable array boundary checking under gcc8.2, so it can help to check if array subscript is out of bound during compilation period, it may give the warning like:
`array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]`

I made a demo using [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18ed9734eea097ba):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    char ch[1];
};

int main() 
{
    volatile A test;
    test.a = 1;
    test.ch[0] = 'a';
    test.ch[1] = 'b';
    test.ch[2] = 'c';
    test.ch[3] = 'd';
    test.ch[4] = '\0';
    std::cout << sizeof(test) << std::endl
              << test.ch[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Compile and run with command:

```
g++ -std=c++11  -O2 -Wall main.cpp  && ./a.out
```

Output is shown below, without any warning or error.

```
8
b
```

So does gcc8.2 support array boundary checking? how to enable it?

**Edit:**

To be further, based on the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57301224/9254404), if remove the `volatile` in line `volatile A test;`, is it possible to enable array boundary checking?

Thanks.

Comment: For runtime checks you can use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and compile using the debug version of the STL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `-Warray-bounds` doesn't warn for arrays at the end of a structures, presumably to avoid false-positives on pre-standardization flexible array members.  To enable that checking, use `-Warray-bounds=2`.  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff55bb3c10f5894c).

Note also that `-Warray-bounds` only works when the `-ftree-vrp` flag is active, which it is by default at `-O2` and higher.