Facing Issue of (prog termination and bad alloc) while processing 2d matrix and storing it by formatting into another 2D matrix
I am working on a program which reads a csv file stores it inside a 2D matrix, and then again reads it tries to format it into a certain style by performing formatting operations. While I am performing those operations during that time the program stops giving an error.
Error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc
I was expecting that the program will completely scan the 2D matrix holding the values of csv and the formatting will happen simultaneously and the whole operation of Scanning the Csv Matrix & creating a Formatted matrix will be done.
Program:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;


// class Record {
// public:
//     string date;
//     string transactionDescription;
//     int credit = 0;
//     int debit = 0;
//     string currency = "INR";  // Set  Default to INR for domestic
//     string cardHolder;
//     string transactionType; // "Domestic" or "International"
//     string location;
// };

// Helper function to trim spaces from a string
string trim(const string& str) {
    size_t first = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
    size_t last = str.find_last_not_of(' ');
    return (first == string::npos || last == string::npos) ? "" : str.substr(first, (last - first + 1));
}

string get_last_word(const string& str) {
    // First, trim the input string
    string trimmed_str = trim(str);
    
    // Find the position of the last space
    size_t last_space = trimmed_str.find_last_of(' ');
    
    // If there is a space, return the substring after the last space
    if (last_space != string::npos) {
        return trimmed_str.substr(last_space + 1);  // Substring after the last space
    }
    
    // If there is no space, return the whole string (it is a single word)
    return trimmed_str;
}

string get_last_word_and_remove(string& str) {
    // Trim the string before processing
    string trimmed_str = trim(str);

    // Find the position of the last space
    size_t last_space = trimmed_str.find_last_of(' ');

    // If there is a space, extract the last word and remove it from the string
    if (last_space != string::npos) {
        string last_word = trimmed_str.substr(last_space + 1);  // Extract the last word
        str = trimmed_str.substr(0, last_space);  // Remove the last word from the original string
        str = trim(str);  // Trim the string again after removal of the word
        return last_word;  // Return the last word
    }

    // If there is no space, the entire string is a single word
    str = "";  // Clear the string as it's a single word
    return trimmed_str;  // Return the whole string
}


bool is_valid_date(const std::string& date_str) {
    string detected_format;
    // Normalize the date by replacing different separators with '-'
    std::string normalized_date = date_str;
    for (char& c : normalized_date) {
        if (c == '/' || c == '.') c = '-';  // Convert all separators to '-'
    }

    // Check if the normalized date has the correct length for a date (e.g., 10 characters: DD-MM-YYYY)
    if (normalized_date.length() != 10) return false;

    // Regular expressions for detecting the formats
    regex dd_mm_yyyy_regex(R"(^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$)");
    regex mm_dd_yyyy_regex(R"(^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$)");
    regex yyyy_mm_dd_regex(R"(^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$)");

    std::smatch match;
    
    // Check for YYYY-MM-DD format
    if (std::regex_match(normalized_date, match, yyyy_mm_dd_regex)) {
        detected_format = "YYYY-MM-DD";
        return true;
    }
    // Check for DD-MM-YYYY format
    if (std::regex_match(normalized_date, match, dd_mm_yyyy_regex)) {
        detected_format = "DD-MM-YYYY";
        return true;
    }
    // Check for MM-DD-YYYY format
    if (std::regex_match(normalized_date, match, mm_dd_yyyy_regex)) {
        detected_format = "MM-DD-YYYY";
        return true;
    }

    // If none of the patterns match, it's not a valid date format
    return false;
}

bool searchCharInVector(const vector<string>& vec, char ch) {
    // Traverse the vector
    for (const string& str : vec) {
        // Traverse each string in the vector
        for (char c : str) {
            // Check if the current character matches the input character
            if (c == ch) {
                return true;  // Return true if the character is found
            }
        }
    }
    return false;  // Return false if the character is not found
}


// Helper function to check if a string is a valid number
bool is_number(const std::string& str) {
    if (str.empty()) return false;
    for (char const &c : str) {
        if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.') return false;  // Allow digits and decimal point
    }
    return true;
}


// Function to process CSV file and store the rows in a 2D vector
void processCSV(const string& file_name, vector<vector<string>>& data) {
    ifstream file(file_name);
    string line;
   

    // Check if the file opened successfully
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file: " << file_name << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Read the file line by line
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        line = trim(line);

        // Skip empty lines
        if (line.empty()) continue;

        // Vector to hold each row's data
        vector<string> row;
        stringstream ss(line);
        string value;

        // Split the line by commas and store values in the row vector
        while (getline(ss, value, ',')) {
            row.push_back(trim(value));  // Trim and push each value to the row
        }

        // Add the row to the 2D vector
        data.push_back(row);
    }

    file.close();  // Close the file after processing

    // Output the 2D vector content
    cout << "Processed CSV Data:" << endl;
    for (const auto& row : data) {
        for (const auto& value : row) {
            cout << value << " | ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Helper function to check if a specific header keyword is present in a row
bool is_present(const vector<string>& row, const string& var) {
    for (const auto& item : row) {
        if (item.find(var) != string::npos) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool is_present(string sem, char c){
    for(int i =0; i<sem.length(); i++){
        if(sem[i]==c){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Function to identify the header and detect which category it belongs to
void identify_header(const vector<vector<string>>& data, int& Date, int& Debit, int& Credit, int& Transaction, int& Amount, int& category) {
    cout<<"Call Received for header identifications"<<endl;
    // Loop through the rows in the CSV data
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        bool present_Date = is_present(data[i], "Date");
        bool present_Transact = is_present(data[i], "Transaction Details") || is_present(data[i], "Transaction Description");
        bool present_Amount = is_present(data[i], "Amount");
        bool present_Debit = is_present(data[i], "Debit");

        bool is_category_one = false;
        bool is_category_two = false;

        // Check if the current row looks like a header
        if (present_Date && present_Transact) {
            // Determine if it's category one or category two based on available columns
            is_category_one = present_Date && present_Debit && present_Transact;
            is_category_two = present_Date && present_Amount && present_Transact;

            if (is_category_one) {
                category = 1;  // Set category as true for category one
                // Assign the column indices for the identified headers
                for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); ++j) {
                    if (data[i][j] == "Date") Date = j;
                    else if (data[i][j] == "Debit") Debit = j;
                    else if (data[i][j] == "Credit") Credit = j;
                    else if (data[i][j] == "Transaction Details" || data[i][j] == "Transaction Description") Transaction = j;
                }
            } else if (is_category_two) {
                category = 2;  
                // Assign the column indices for the identified headers
                for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); ++j) {
                    if (data[i][j] == "Date") Date = j;
                    else if (data[i][j] == "Amount") Amount = j;
                    else if (data[i][j] == "Transaction Details" || data[i][j] == "Transaction Description") Transaction = j;
                }
            }

            // If header is found, we can exit the loop
            if (is_category_one || is_category_two) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    cout<<"Headers identified"<<endl;
}

bool is_blank(vector<string> sample){
    for(int i = 0; i<sample.size();i++){
        if(sample[i].length()>0){
            return false;
        } 
        
    }
    cout<<"Blank Line Identified"<<endl;
    return true;
}

void standardFormat(vector<vector<string>>& data, vector<vector<string>> database) {

    cout<<"Call Received to Standard Format"<<endl;
    string transaction_type = "Domestic Transactions";  // Default value

    // Start the traversal of the data
    int size = data.size();
    cout << size << endl;

    // Variables to store indices of important columns
    int Date = -1;
    int Debit = -1;
    int Credit = -1;
    int Transaction_Details = -1;
    int Amount = -1;
    int category = -1;  // Use -1 to represent uninitialized state
    string card_name; 
    string currency  = "INR";

    int p =0;

    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        p++;
        cout<<"Processing row: "<<p <<endl;
        // Transact Details 
        
        if(is_blank(data[row])) continue;

        // Check if the current row contains "Domestic Transactions" or "International Transactions"

        // Checking if the transaction type is International or Domestic
        string transact = "Domestic Transactions";
        bool present = is_present(data[row], transact);  // Use the correct name for the check
        if (present) {
            transaction_type = transact;
            cout<<"Transaction Type Changed"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout<<"Not Domestic Transaction"<<endl;

        transact = "International Transactions";
        present = is_present(data[row], transact); 
        if(present) {
            transaction_type = transact;
            cout<<"Transaction Type Changed"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout<<"not International Transaction"<<endl;
        // Checking for the header row
        if (category == -1) {
            identify_header(data, Date, Debit, Credit, Transaction_Details, Amount, category);
            continue;
        }
        
        // If the current row is a header row, skip it
        else if (is_present(data[row], "Date") && 
            (is_present(data[row], "Transaction Details") || is_present(data[row], "Transaction Description"))) {
            cout<<"Current row is Header skipping this row"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        
        else if(searchCharInVector(data[row],'-')){
            cout<<"Not Header File"<<endl;
            //category 1
            if(category == 1){
                if(transaction_type == "Domestic Transactions"){
                    string place = get_last_word(data[row][Transaction_Details]);
                    vector<string> solution  = {data[row][Date], data[row][Transaction_Details], data[row][Debit], data[row][Credit], currency, card_name, transaction_type, place};
                    cout<<"Data Inserted: "<<endl;
                    cout<<data[row][Date]<<" "<<data[row][Transaction_Details]<<" "<<data[row][Debit]<<" "<<data[row][Credit]<<" "<<currency<<" "<<card_name<<" "<<transaction_type<<" "<<place<<endl;
                    database.push_back(solution);
                }
                else{
                    currency = get_last_word_and_remove(data[row][Transaction_Details]);
                    string place = get_last_word(data[row][Transaction_Details]);
                    vector<string> solution  = {data[row][Date], data[row][Transaction_Details], data[row][Debit], data[row][Credit], currency, card_name, transaction_type, place};
                    cout<<"Data Inserted: "<<endl;
                    cout<<data[row][Date]<<" "<<data[row][Transaction_Details]<<" "<<data[row][Debit]<<" "<<data[row][Credit]<<" "<<currency<<" "<<card_name<<" "<<transaction_type<<" "<<place<<endl;
                    database.push_back(solution);
                }
                
            }
            else{
                // // Category 2
                // if(transaction_type == "Domestic Transsactions"){
                //     string place = get_last_word(data[row][Transaction_Details]);
                //     string possCredit = data[row][Amount];
                //     vector<string> solution;
                //     bool isCredit = 0; // Bydefault
                //     if(is_present(possCredit,'c')){
                //         possCredit = get_last_word_and_remove(data[row][Amount]);
                //         isCredit = 1;
                //     }
                //     if(isCredit)    solution = {data[row][Date], data[row][Transaction_Details], "", data[row][Amount], currency, card_name, transaction_type, place};
                   //  else    solution = {data[row][Date], data[row][Transaction_Details],  data[row][Amount],"", currency, card_name, transaction_type, place};
                //     database.push_back(solution);
                // }
                // else{
                    currency = get_last_word_and_remove(data[row][Transaction_Details]);

                    string possCredit = data[row][Amount];
                    vector<string> solution;
                    string place = get_last_word(data[row][Transaction_Details]);
                    bool isCredit = 0;
                    if(is_present(possCredit,'c')){
                        possCredit = get_last_word_and_remove(data[row][Amount]);
                        isCredit = 1;
                    }
                    if(isCredit)    solution = {data[row][Date], data[row][Transaction_Details], "", data[row][Amount], currency, card_name, transaction_type, place};
                    else    solution = {data[row][Date], data[row][Transaction_Details],  data[row][Amount],"", currency, card_name, transaction_type, place};
                    database.push_back(solution);
                // }

            }

        }
        else{
            cout<<"Not Data"<<endl;
            cout<<"Name Present"<<endl;
            if(category == 1){
                if(data[row][Credit].length()!=0)   card_name = data[row][Credit];
                else card_name = data[row][Debit];
            }
            else{
                // category 2 
                if(data[row][Transaction_Details].length() != 0)    card_name = data[row][Transaction_Details];
                else card_name = data[row][Date];
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    cout<<"Processed row:  "<<p<<endl;
}



int main() {
    string file_name = "Axis-Input-Case3.csv";
    vector<vector<string>> data;

    // Call function to process the CSV file and store data in 2D vector
    processCSV(file_name, data);
    cout<<"CSV file processed"<<endl;
    
    vector<vector<string>> database;
    vector<string> temp  = {"Date", "Transaction Description", "Debit", "Credit", "Currency", "Card Name", "Transaction Type", "Location"};
    database.push_back(temp);
    cout<<database[0][0]<<endl;
    cout<<data[5][3].length()<<endl;
    standardFormat(data,database);
    cout<<"Standardization Completed"<<endl;
    cout<<database.size();
    cout<<data.size();

    return 0;
}


Supplied CSV Values file
,,Domestic Transactions,
"Date      ",Debit,Credit,Transaction Details
,,Rahul,
,,,
28-01-2018,1099,,INDIAN RAILWAY CATERINGNEW DELHI
28-01-2018,34980,,FLIPKART INTERNET PRIVA BANGALORE
28-01-2018,660,,TIPSY CATERERS JAIPUR
29-01-2018,57181,,MAKEMYTRIP INDIA PVT LT NEWDELHI
29-01-2018,,3390,INDIAN RAILWAY CATERING NEWDELHI
29-01-2018,,53326,MAKEMYTRIP INDIA PVT LT NEWDELHI
30-01-2018,,680,INDIAN RAILWAY CATERING NEWDELHI
,,,
"Date      ",Debit,Credit,Transaction Details
,,Ritu,
,,,
22-02-2018,,1845,FEETOES GURGAON
18-02-2018,949,,DECATHLON SPORTS INDIA GURGAON
09-02-2018,1250,,SILVER GALERIE A UNIT    GURGAON
23-02-2018,,1650,DNA PHARMACY           GURUGRAM
26-02-2018,,413,MONTE CARLO            GURGAON
27-02-2018,,456,THE ROOM               GURGAON
27-02-2018,1938,,LITTLE BURGUNDY        GURGAON
,,,
,,,
,,International Transactions,
"Date      ",Debit,Credit,Transaction Details
,,Rahul,
,,,
13-01-2018,9,,SRILANKANUPGRADE KATUNAYAKE         EUR
14-01-2018,,6,HEALTHGUARD LIMITED KATUNAYAKE      USD
17-01-2018,19,,FOOT RUB BERLIN                  EUR
28-01-2018,108,,California Games CALIFORNIA         USD
30-01-2018,219,,NewYorkShop NEWYORK                 USD
03-02-2018,8,,EURO WINGS DUSSELDOR                EUR
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,

:

Please run your program under a debugger and edit the question with a call stack.

In the first vector<string> solution = { data[row][Date],... , Date is -1 and therefore you access the data out of bounds. Compile with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG and read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking

I was expecting that the program will... -- Every programmer has written a program that does not initially work correctly.  What do they do if this happens?  They debug the code that they have written.  Just putting up the code with no other description of where in the code you believe the problem is may get you downvoted.  Yes, fixing the issue may be difficult, but you should know where the problem is located.
